# navigating between different screens and passing objects

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am new to MVC..

I have a Customer Add screen. I have developed Controller, Model, and View screen for it. This is easy.

Now I have to deal with Order screen, and 2 additional screens that deal with Order Detail.

So.. First user fills out Order screen, then clicks the next button, and goes to Order Detail1 screen. Fills out some more information. Then hits the next button and goes to Order Detail2 screen and fills out some more information. When done, customer clicks the Save button and the whole Order is saved.

I do not know how to 
1. Pass order object from the Order screen to Order Detail1 and then pass objects from here to Order Detail2 screen.

Between the 3 screens, how would I set up Controller, Model, and View classes? Would there be each Controller, Model, and View for Order, OrderDetail1, and OrderDetail2?

How all the 3 would connect with each other such that .. in the end .. I would hit save in OrderDetail2 and every thing gets saved?

I am just looking for high level hints so I can start to google for those concepts. Right now, I am even confused what MVC terms would I be searching for...

Comment: you could use session object to store passing objects

Comment: duplicate question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5181695/mvc3-multi-step-form-how-to-persist-model-object

Comment: polybios .. thanks for the link .. I will check it out..

Comment: StackOverFlow nazis .. if you are going to downvote my question.. at least provide reasons. just so that you know.. I did try hard to search for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't use a jquery wizard and put all information on the same screen?

http://thecodemine.org/#_demoForm=sweden

Comment: I can't do that... I have to strictly follow the requirement doc.